# parse a JSON Binary tree to visualize

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

I need to parse a JSON file which is a binary tree. Also the depth of the nested tree is unknown. i.e. leftNode can be any deep.

```
 leftNode= can be a binary/operator or a sub tree
 center= always Operator
 rightNode= alwasy a value/expression.
```

Here is the JSON file:

```
jsonInput={
   "leftNode": {
       "leftNode": {
            "leftNode": {
               "leftNode": {
                   "leftNode": "brand_name",
                   "rightNode": "brand_id",
                   "centerOperator": "OR"
               },
               "rightNode": "category_name",
               "centerOperator": "AND"
           },
           "rightNode": "latitude",
           "centerOperator": "AND"
       },
       "rightNode": "latitude",
       "centerOperator": "AND"
    },
    "rightNode": "radius",
    "centerOperator": "AND"
}
```

How do I iterate over such file.
I want to convert this into this a tree like structure.
thank you

Comment: Why have you tagged your question with "jquery" and "angular"?

Comment: Because i want to convert this using angular or jquery. @MaxArt